# Altering the Title of node using Preprocess

Tags: nodes, theming

I am trying to alter the page title of history content type using this function

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   if(isset($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->type == "your_content_type") {
   drupal_set_title("my_title");    
 }
}
```

But you know what, I dont get anything in node array.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`hook_node_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7), which also gives you more flexibility, (e.g. control what view mode / language you affect):

```
function MY_MODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($node->type == 'your-node-type' && $view_mode == 'full') {
    drupal_set_title('your-title');
}
```

Instead of using a preprocess function, which is better for template changes, (for example, adding variables to it):

> The main role of the preprocessors is to set up variables to be placed
>   within the template (.tpl.php) files.

[Preprocess and process functions](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430)